# pySerial running command to list ports

Tags: pyserial

I am using pySerial and I am running this command using CMD to list available COM ports and displays a COM port number when found:

```
python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

I know that the command line will import the serial module when I use the python -m flag and I can access the objects inside it so it should show the output. However, the same command however does not work when run using the IDLE shell:

```
import serial
print(serial.tools.list_ports_common)
```

This returns an error AttributeError: module 'serial' has no attribute 'tools'
Why is it not working at IDLE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import it first:

```
from serial.tools import list_ports
list_ports.main()  # Same result as python -m serial.tools.list_ports
```

You can check out the source [here](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/tools/list_ports.py)

Comment: Thanks. That solves it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try connecting to each possible port (COM0...COM255). Then add the ports with successful connections to a list.  Here is my example:

```
import serial

def connectedCOMports ():
    allPorts = [] #list of all possible COM ports
    for i in range(256):
        allPorts.append("COM" + str(i))

    ports = [] #a list of COM ports with devices connected
    for port in allPorts:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port) #attempt to connect to the device
            s.close()
            ports.append(port) #if it can connect, add it the the list
        except:
            pass #if it can't connect, don't add it to the list
    return(ports)

print(connectedCOMports())
```

When I ran this program, it printed ['COM7'] to the console.  This represents the ESP32 microcontroller that I connected to my USB port.